# What's the difference between drift, intercept, and mean?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, terminology, intercept

In R, `stats::arima` has a parameter named `include.mean`, and its result can contain a component named "intercept". For example,

```
> arima(arima.sim(model=list(ar=.9), n=100) + 42, order=c(1, 0, 0))

Call:
arima(x = arima.sim(model = list(ar = 0.9), n = 100) + 42, order = c(1, 0, 0))

Coefficients:
         ar1  intercept
      0.7885    41.2004
s.e.  0.0616     0.4032

sigma^2 estimated as 0.779:  log likelihood = -129.89,  aic = 265.78
```

Despite the presence of "intercept", the document of `forecast::Arima` says

> Largely a wrapper for the `arima` function in the stats package. The main difference is that this function allows a drift term.

What's more, [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/62250/108877) indicated that "R uses conventions and parametrizations that differ from what (OP) expect".

I wonder what's the difference between these terms?

Comment: In my [answer here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/311177/estimation-of-arp-model-by-lm-versus-arima-in-r-different-results/311253#311253) I mention "Also, and this makes everything much more confusing, the arima function will call its mean the intercept. This is a well-known issue covered in other questions such as [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60803/r-time-series-issues) one, and is also explained [here](https://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa2/Rissues.htm)."

Comment: @Taylor This is exactly the answer I'm referring to! It didn't explictly address which parametrization is used in R, though.

Comment: [another one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/340838/good-resource-for-converting-arima-output-in-r-to-equation-form/340863#340863)